# Array of Arrays, delete an index based on the contents of the array at the index?

Tags: ruby

I've been struggling learning how to deal with arrays made up of arrays.

Say I had this array:

```
my_array = [['ORANGE',1],['APPLE',2],['PEACH',3]
```

How would I go about finding the my_array index that contains 'apple' and deleting that index (removing the sub-array ['APPLE',2] because 'apple' was conatined in the array at that index) ?

Thanks - I really appreciate the help from here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Array.select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000251) to filter out items:

```
>> a = [['ORANGE',1],['APPLE',2],['PEACH',3]]
=> [["ORANGE", 1], ["APPLE", 2], ["PEACH", 3]]

>> a.select{ |a, b| a != "APPLE" }
=> [["ORANGE", 1], ["PEACH", 3]]
```

`select` will return those items from the, for which the given block (here `a != "APPLE"`) returns `true`.

Answer (score 6):

```
my_array.reject { |x| x[0] == 'APPLE' }
```

Comment: Tho I think The MYYN's deconstructing yield (I think that's what it's called) is nice.

Comment: A variation of this: `a.reject { |x, y| x == 'APPLE' }`

Comment: Girish Rao, that's fine, good point.  I suppose, for practice, I could argue that `reject` will work for any `Enumerable` and not just `Array`, but that argument could cut both ways: since `delete_if` is implemented *only* for `Array` you can probably count on it running quickly.

Comment: You'll find `reject` and its counterpart `select` used a lot more than `delete_if`. I think it's because they're more generic, used more often, and easier to remember as a result.

Answer (score 4):

I tested this, it works:

```
my_array.delete_if { |x| x[0] == 'APPLE' }
```

Comment: Using delete_if seems really human readable to me.  I love this place - 3 almost instant answers all different and all of them work.  I learned a lot - thanks all!